# Iterate through a root directory and get all files in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi 
i am creating a application and i want to know the each and every file which is present under that one folder .i.e. how can i iterate through a root directory and get the each files visit at list once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to list them all at once, you can just use the overload for GetFiles that includes the option.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Obviously, in a web app you wouldn't likely have access to "c:\MyDir", so you can replace that with a variable holding the results of a MapPath call like so:

```
var rootDir = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Directory.EnumerateFiles(String, String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) function with `SearchOption.AllDirectories`:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

EnumerateFiles method is way faster than GetFiles method since it actually just returns the enumerator and does not actually access the files until they are red.

Comment: Figures there would be something in the framework that would do it for you. This only returns the full path though. Extra work would be needed if you wanted to get an object that represented file properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DirectoryInfo and FileInfo classes as well as a recursive function.

```
void Main()
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Personal");
    ListContents(info);
}

public void ListContents(DirectoryInfo info)
{
    foreach(var dir in info.GetDirectories())
    {
        ListContents(dir);
    }
    foreach(var file in info.GetFiles())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
    }
}
```